# why @font-face in ie10 so difficult

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, browser, fonts

Like others I am having problems using custom fonts in InternetExplorer. Now, I have seen a number of threads on the topic, all of which end up in a solution where I need to not only embed the trueType font (which is enough for all other major browsers) but something similar to this is suggested:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: "LCD";
 src: url('/Public/Fonts/quartz_regular-webfont.eot');
 src: url('/Public/Fonts/quartz_regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'),
      url('/Public/Fonts/quartz_regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('/Public/Fonts/quartz_regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('/Public/Fonts/quartz_regular-webfont.svg#quartzregular') format('svg');
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
```

Could someone explain to me why InternetExplorer requires my font in trueType, webFont, svg AND embeddedOpentype in order to work?? Such a hassle...

Answer (score -1):

Try using [this](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).  It seems to have helped others out.  It doesn't work with all fonts, but go ahead and give it a try.

Comment: Yes, I know how to work around it, I am just interested as to why IE needs the font i 4 formats before displaying anything correctly...